# Handling JSON with Boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm interested whether there exists a library for working with JSON in
Boost that preserves data types?

I know about property_tree, but if I read a valid JSON with it and then
write it out it results in all fields being strings. This is because
property_tree internally does not distinguish different value types. But
I need something that can read e.g.

```
{"number":42}
```

get access to it and write it then in the same form. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSON Spirit](https://github.com/sirikata/json-spirit)** is based on Boost, and can be used for reading/writing json while preserving basic types. It requires transforming to variant type objects for holding the type information.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-spirit

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot. It looks like a solution I've been looking for.